# Does Toyota Camry LE support mounting of fog lights?

Tags: toyota, camry

[image]

Toyota Camry SE has standard fog lights integrated. LE edition has no standard fog lights. According to feature spreadsheet, fog lights are not even optional in LE. But in above screenshot from a video, I circled in red fog lights on LE.

My question is : how difficult to mount fog lights on LE? Is it possible to do this in Toyota maintenance center? Or does this require extra efforts?

I see that with regard to 2015 edition, neither LE nor SE has fog lights.

Please answer separately for models of 2014, 2015, and later (after Restyling).

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The bumper is plastic. Mounting a fog light by drilling a large enough hole shouldn't be too hard. You then need some kind of wiring from the battery, and a switch at the dashboard. None of this is rocket science.

However, if the car has no standard fog lights, I bet Toyota dealership will answer that it can't be done. Do it yourself or find an independent mechanic that is willing to do the job (which can cost a lot, as it requires bumper modifications and new wiring!)

The answer, by the way, is applicable to all cars with a plastic bumper that has a location where in theory fog lights could be added.